# What transform can I use to "zoom" in a specific portion of a signal's spectrum?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

If I recall correctly, there is a variation of the DFT that can be used to analyze a specific band of the spectrum of a signal. How is it called?

Comment: [It is called the Chirp-Z-Transform.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluestein's_FFT_algorithm)

Comment: @Mohammad: "One common question is : Is the zoom FFT the same as the chirp z-transform. The answer is : Absolutely not." http://www.numerix-dsp.com/zoomfft.html  Would be a good answer to explain the relationship.

Comment: @endolith Not the same sure, but they are different ways of arriving at the same end result. The 'Zoom-FFT' involves downsampling / BPF / FFT, whereas the Chirp-Z Transform evaluates the Z-transform on the band you want. I have heard people refer to 'Chirp-Z' as 'Zoom-FFT' as in its particular application.

Answer (score 9):

You're probably referring to the [zoom FFT](http://arc.id.au/ZoomFFT.html). It's essentially a technique that allows for complexity reduction in the case where you have a small portion of a larger band that you'd like to analyze at high spectral resolution. It prevents you from having to calculate the high-resolution frequency content in the bands that you don't care about. Roughly, the algorithm can be summarized as follows:

- Apply a bandpass filter around the region of interest, eliminating the components outside the band that you care about.
- Decimate the signal by a factor $D$, such that the resulting sample rate still meets the Nyquist criterion for the filter's passband width. Depending upon where the band's center frequency was, this process might also involve frequency-translating the signal to baseband.
- Perform a DFT on the signal. In order to get the same frequency resolution at the output, the "zoomed" transform only requires a transform length that is $\frac{1}{D}$-th of what you would need to use if you used the original, unfiltered signal for your analysis.